# How to remotely access IP camera on a closed network with private IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, remote-access, camera

I would like to see if there is a way to access my new IP camera that I just bought on a network that's connected to the internet through another router, to which I don't have admin access.

Here is the setup:

My iMac is connected to a large school network through wifi (I'm leasing an office space in their building) and I'm sharing the internet connection to my router through an ethernet cable, creating my own wifi. My camera is connected to this wifi, so I have no problem accessing it while on a local network. I don't have admin access to the school's network, so I cannot setup port forwarding on the main router that's accepting the internet connection.

Any ideas on how to solve it? I thought of using the RTSP through VLC player, but these cameras don't support the RTSP.

The camera I have is Foscam FI8918W.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution (assuming you've got a Mac at home too) would be to sign onto your iCloud account and turn on Back to My Mac (BTMM) and screen sharing on both Macs. BTMM is great at getting through firewalls and NAT gateways without admin access, static port mappings, uPnP, NAT-PMP, PCP (Port Control Protocol), etc. Then you could control your work Mac from home and connect to the camera from your work Mac. Not sure what the video quality and framerate would be for that solution, but it's zero cost and fairly quick and hassle-free to set up.